# Monotouch Dialog Custom Element and GetHeight not being called

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Using Monotouch 5.2.11 iOS

I have followed this tutorial (http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html), created a custom cell with an image and have also added the IElementSizing Interface.  The GetHeight is never called.

Similar questions have been asked and the generally accepted solution was to make sure and create the RootElements first, set the UnEvenRows=true before adding them to the Controller.  This did not work. I've tried that as well as about every other combination of adding sections to root elements and have not ever seen the GetHeight fired.

The MyDataElement is an image that is 320x200 which displays fine, but the string element that comes after it is not shown (assuming it is behind it).  Consequently if I drag the custom cell up above the top, it disappears, reappears, and the second stringelement displays on top of it.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
public class MyDataElement : Element, IElementSizing {
 static NSString key = new NSString ("myDataElement");
 public MyData MyData;

 public MyDataElement (MyData myData) : base (null)
 {
      MyData = myData;
 }

public  float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){
    return  200f;   // break point here is never hit ever   
 }

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
 {
      var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell (key) as MyDataCell;
      if (cell == null)
           cell = new MyDataCell (MyData, key);
      else
           cell.UpdateCell (MyData);

      return cell;
 }

public partial class TableTester : DialogViewController
{


    public TableTester () : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
    {


    var re = new RootElement("Sample") { 
            new Section("Testy") {
                new MyDataElement(new MyData() { stuff="hello"}),
                new StringElement("Sample")
            }
        };
        re.UnevenRows = true;


        this.Root = re;

        //this.Root = root;
    }

}
```

In addition to that I've even done this which didn't work either:

```
public class TestNavigator : UINavigationController {

    public TestNavigator() {

        TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem("Test", null, 1);

        var re = new RootElement("Sample") { 
            new Section("Sammy") {

                new StringElement("Sample"),
                new MyDataElement(new MyData() { stuff="sam"}),
                new StringElement("Sample 2")
            }
        };
        re.UnevenRows = true;
        var dv = new DialogViewController(re);
        re.UnevenRows = true;

        PushViewController(dv, true);

    }
```

Comment: I had downloaded Monotouch.Dialog from github to review the ImageLoader code and was using that as the reference in my project.  After removing the reference and using the built in Monotouch.Dialog the problem has been fixed.  The IElementSizing doesn't work from github: <https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog>

Comment: The text you pasted is not enough to reproduce the problem.   But in general, the UnevenRows property is automatically computed, setting it wont really do much for you

Comment: Thanks. It was fixed when I removed the Monolog.Dialog reference from the github downloaded project and used the built in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plenty of trial and error, I had to make sure and remove the reference to Monotouch.Dialog that I had downloaded from github and use the built in reference.  It seems that the getheight maybe broken in github.